# simplification of expression to get value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

I need help in solving this question.
how can get the value for degree?

```
equation: 
x = 9.8 * sin( degree * ( PI /180) )
```

where i know the value of degree

```
suppose 
degree = 50
x = 9.8 * sin( 50 * ( 3.14 /180) )
x = 7.51
```

now from the value of X i need to reverse and find the value for degree

```
where x = 7.51
7.51 = 9.8 * sin(degree * (3.14/180))
expected answer = 50
```

what i expect is degree = 50
but i don't know how to simplify the formula and value evolution.

i also don't know even its possible or not so please if not possible then downgrade the question so i delete it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $5=9.8*s$ for $s$? Do you know how to solve $\sin(x)=\#$ for $x$? Please edit in the context and what you know and anything you've tried.

Comment: @MarkS. i have edited hope you get this

Comment: But you didn't answer the questions @Mark asked. Do you know how to solve $\sin x=y$ for $x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson no, i don't know.

Comment: Then I suggest you find out about "the inverse sine function," sometimes written $\arcsin x$, sometimes written $\sin^{-1}x$ (but **not** the same thing as $(\sin x)^{-1}$).

Comment: Making any progress, vyom?

Comment: degree = asin( 7.51 /9.8)  * ( 180/ PI )

Comment: @GerryMyerson partially yes. its only work if degree value under 90. for example for degree value 120 its not worked as expected. i think i have lack of knowledge about trigonometry :(

Comment: If two angles, $r$ and $s$, add up to 180 degrees, then they have the same sine; if all you know is the value of the sine, then you can't distinguish between $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Understood, vyom?